# Why is ServiceStack.Client project missing from v3 branch?

Tags: servicestack

I'd like to create a personal derivative of the free and open source licensed version of ServiceStack (v3) but the v3 branch on GitHub does not contain the ServiceStack.Client project. Was that an oversight and can it be corrected?

Answer (score 2):

The v3 client is in version 3.9.x of the `ServiceStack.Common` NuGet package, in the `ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web` namespace, as [documented here](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki/C%23-client).

Comment: Thank you. That explains why I could not find it.